# how to make call using plivo in Android

Tags: android, plivo

I'm trying to call using `plivo`. Its working fine well in `iOS` `plivo` example but I unable to call using android example? I have use same endpoint what I use in ios but still unable to call. I feel something file is missing in the path "`com.plivo.example.outbound.Call` (Call - is missing)". I have use source from git plivo example, I'm using android studio help me to fix this.

Comment: what exactly do you mean, WHAT is plivo? Is it an app? What are you trying to do.

Comment: plivo.com is an voip provider, I'm using this and trying to make call, its fine in ios and i'm looking for android.

Answer (score 0):

The Plivo Android SDK is quite easy to set up and use. After endpoint.login(username, password), just call endpoint.createOutgoingCall();